# How to update data in my xamarin forms app using php script, mysql and webservice?

Tags: php, mysql, xamarin, xamarin.forms, auto-update

I've created a profile page as you can see beneath. I've also made a edit profile button at the end of the page but i would like that this button works. I have also a database(MySql) connected to my app which i'm using for registration and login, so i was wondering if it's possible to edit user data (username, email and age) with a php script? What is important to know: when the data is edited, it has also to be updated in the database automaticly.

Could somebody help me with this or does somebody have some example code or URL?

Thanks!

[image: Profile page]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/data-cloud/web-services/

Comment: Send the user data to your server side through api every time after user updated, and then update those data in your database. Every time user go to this page, get the data from your database and show it.